# How to display an istanceof an object in an arraylist? (Polymorphism)

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

I am trying to display all of the elements in the ArrayList plantList.
My main program will add, delete, search, filter, and display all of the plants of four different child classes. Everything "seems" to be working except when I display. 
~I will only including portions of my code that are relevant to the questions.

A little background: I am a student and this is my first time working with inheritance/polymorphism.

1)How do I distinguish between the different objects since they all have different parameters, at the time of displaying?

2) Any suggestions on how to improve the performance/logic of what I'm doing? A little explanation would be great.

//Parent class

```
public class Plant{

   private String name;
   private String id;
   private String color;

   public Plant(String name, String id, String color){
   this.name = name;
   this.id = id;
   this.color = color;

   }

   public String getName(){

      return this.name;
   }

   public void setName(String name){

      name = this.name;  
   }

   public String getId(){

      return this.id;
   }

   public void setId(String id){

      id = this.id;  
   }

   public String getColor(){

      return this.color;
   }

   public void setColor(String color){
      color = this.color;  
   }


}
```

//one of several child classes

```
   public class Flower extends Plant{

   private boolean thorns;
   private boolean smell;   

   public Flower(String name, String id, String color, boolean blnThorns, boolean blnSmell){
      super(name, id, color);
      thorns = blnThorns;
      smell = blnSmell;

   }

   public boolean isThorns(){

      return thorns;
   }

   public void setThorns(boolean blnThorns){
      thorns = blnThorns;  
   }

   public boolean isSmell(){

      return smell;
   }

   public void setSmell(boolean blnSmell){
      smell = blnSmell;  
   }


}
```

// portion of the main driver

```
ArrayList<Plant> plantList = new ArrayList<Plant>();

//adding a flower to the plantList
System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the flower to add: ");
            name = add.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nEnter the ID code: ");
            id = add.nextLine(); 

            System.out.println("\nEnter the color: ");
            color = add.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nAre there thorns present? (True/False) ");
            blnThorns = add.nextBoolean();

            System.out.println("\nDoes the flower smell? (True/False) ");
            blnSmell = add.nextBoolean();

            plantList.add(new Flower(name, id, color, blnThorns, blnSmell));

            System.out.println("Flower inserted.");
            System.out.println();
            break;

//displaying all plants
for( int i = 0; i < plantList.size(); i++){
      System. out.println("\t" + (i+1) + ":");
            System.out.print("\n\tName: " + plantList.get(i).getName());
            System.out.print("\n\tName: " + plantList.get(i).getId());
            System.out.print("\n\tColor: " + plantList.get(i).getColor());
            if(plantList instanceof Flower){ // HERE I am not sure what I'm doing or how to do it
            System.out.print("\n\tThorns presence: " + plantList.get(i).isThorns()); /* this is an example of what is not working properly */
            System.out.print("\n\tSmell presence: " + plantList.get(i).isSmell());  /* this is an example of what is not working properly*/
            System.out.println("\n");
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "display" you mean "print some sort of string to the console or other output", then the answer is fairly simple: there's no need to use `instanceof` at all. All you need to do is override the [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method in each different class that you want to be displayable, then when you want to display an object (even if you don't know exactly what type it is), just call `toString` on it and print the result. Polymorphism will do the job of picking *which* `toString` method implementation to call.

Here's how it would look in your specific example.

In the Plant class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return "\n\tName: " + getName()
        + "\n\tName: " + getId()
        + "\n\tColor: " + getColor();
}
```

Then, in the Flower class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return super.toString()
        + "\n\tThorns presence: " + isThorns()
        + "\n\tSmell presence: " + isSmell();
}
```

Finally, to display all plants:

```
for (Plant plant : plantList) {
   System.out.println(plant);
}
```

Note that `toString` is called automatically when you pass any `Object` to `System.out.println`.

Comment: Okay, can you explain this a little bit further? a very quick example. Doesn't need to be using my code.

Comment: Great answer, good job on highlighting the use of polymorphism! :)

Comment: This is actually a very nice example of polymorphism. +1  If OP only needs to display the object, this is a great answer.  If OP needs to call `Flower` specific methods like `isThorns()` or `isSmell()`, then there is no way around casting.  But I have to give it to you.  I think **OP should give you the answer on this one**. And you are also accomplishing his primary goal of teaching him about the power of polymorphism!

Answer (score 0):

You were really close.  You just needed to check against the ***element*** of the list, not the list itself, when you did the `instanceof` check.  Then, if it is in fact an instance of `Flower`, then you need to cast the list element to a `Flower` and make the method calls from there.

Like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < plantList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("\t" + (i+1) + ":");
    System.out.print("\n\tName: " + plantList.get(i).getName());
    System.out.print("\n\tName: " + plantList.get(i).getId());
    System.out.print("\n\tColor: " + plantList.get(i).getColor());
    if (plantList.get(i) instanceof Flower) {
        Flower flower = (Flower)plantList.get(i);
        System.out.print("\n\tThorns presence: " + flower.isThorns());
        System.out.print("\n\tSmell presence: " + flower.isSmell());
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct and answers the question, but it is not the best way to solve the problem. Since the asker specifically mentioned polymorphism in his question, and polymorphism is a good way to solve the problem, I think an answer using polymorphism is more appropriate.

Comment: @RedRoboHood: Thank you for leaving a comment. I actually do appreciate that.  But even though his question does mention polymorphism, if you look at the code, you will see that what he's actually trying to do is call `Flower` specific methods that are not in `Plant`.  Casting is necessary in this case.  Also, it's usually frowned upon to downvote an answer unless it's a really terrible answer that is dangerous.  I'll assume you didn't know that :)  But have a look at the section [When should I vote down?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: This did work. I would like to learn the point of polymorphism though. As of now I don't really see the big picture yet.

Comment: @d_PI: You are right.  Your code is currently not a good example of what polymorphism can do for you.  I'll see if I can find a good link for you to read and I'll add a comment for you.

Comment: @d_PI: Have a read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), and I'm sure you can find more info.  But basically, polymorphism is useful when child classes **override** parent class behavior by **overriding** methods from the parent's class.  It'll take a while before you see the full picture, but it is powerful, you'll see.

Comment: @sstan I would disagree that any `Flower`-specific methods need to be called (see my updated answer), so I think `instanceof` is still unnecessary here. You're right, I didn't know about when to downvote. Thanks for pointing that out! I'll try to be better about it in the future. :)

Comment: @d_PI: It's completely up to you, but I really think you should change the accepted answer to RedRoboHood's answer. Thanks.